# Splitting a column into multiple columns based on the text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple requirement! I receive "excess" information as a text field. It will have values like "£100 Per Year", "£225 Per Condition", "£105 per Accident" etc...I need to load the excess amount from this field into three fields of the target table.

For a policy, "P001" could have 3 different types of excess amounts like "ExcessPerYear", "ExcessPerCondition" and "ExcessPerAccident". Based on the source data I need to decide where to load the excess amount.

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceData
(Excess VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO #SourceData
VALUES
('£500 Per Year'),
('£50 Per Condition Per Year'),
('£450 Per Condition'),
('£200 Per Accident'),
('£100 Per Accident Per Year')
```

```
Select * From #SourceData
```

| Excess |
| --- |
| £500 Per Year |
| £50 Per Condition Per Year |
| £450 Per Condition |
| £200 Per Accident |
| £100 Per Accident Per Year |

I want the output be like the following

| Excess | ExcessPerYear | ExcessPerAccident | ExcessPerCondition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| £500 Per Year | 500 | Null | Null |
| £50 Per Condition Per Year | Null | Null | 50 |
| £450 Per Condition | Null | Null | 450 |
| £200 Per Accident | Null | 200 | Null |
| £100 Per Accident Per Year | Null | 100 | Null |

So basically, whenever the excess has a string like "Per Year" then the amount should be mapped to "ExcessPerYear" field. If The string has values like "Per Condition Per Year" or "Per Condition" then the excess amount should be loaded into "ExcessPerCondition" Table and finally if the text is like "Per Accident" or "Per Accident per Year" then it should be loaded into "ExcessPerAccident" field.

I have wrote the following code. It is giving me expected result, however I wanted to ask the community if there's any better way of writing the code?

I am using SQL Server 2019 Standard edition.

```
;WITH GetAllElements 
AS 
(
    SELECT  
            Excess
           ,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][a-z]%',Excess) AS Pos_FirstStr
           ,LEN(Excess) AS LenOfStr
           ,SUBSTRING(Excess,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][a-z]%',Excess),LEN(Excess)) AS Strng
           ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Excess) AS Pos_FirstNum
           ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',REPLACE(Excess,'£','')) AS Pos_LastNum
           ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(Excess,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Excess),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',REPLACE(Excess,'£','')))) AS ExcessAmount
       
    FROM #SourceData SD
)

SELECT  
       Excess
      ,CASE WHEN Strng='Per Year' THEN ExcessAmount ELSE NULL END AS ExcessPerYear
      ,CASE WHEN Strng IN ('Per Accident','Per Accident Per Year') THEN ExcessAmount ELSE NULL END AS ExcessPerAccident
      ,CASE WHEN Strng IN ('Per Condition Per Year','Per Condition') THEN ExcessAmount ELSE NULL END AS ExcessPerCondition
FROM GetAllElements
```

I know I don't need the CTE. I think all I need is those 3 case statements but I wrote the CTE just to make the code look clean and easy for everyone to understand.

Comment: define better:  Faster? Easier to read? More maintainable?

Comment: Your question *implies* that Per Year has the highest priority, and Per Accident the lowest, but your expected results disagree. Why is `'£100 Per Accident Per Year'` put in the `Per Accident` columns and not the `Per Year` column? What if it were `'£100 Per Year Per Accident'` instead? What about `'£250 Per Condition Per Accident'`?

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Comment: sorry @Larnu, I have entered wrong information in the table. Basically, if it is "Per Accident Per Year" or "Per Accident" it should go into "ExcessPerAccident" and similarly "Per Condition" or "Per Condition Per Year" should go into "ExcesPerCondition" and finally "Per Year" should go into "ExcessPerYear"

Comment: @MitchWheat - Faster and Maintainable...I can make it easily readable

Comment: @Larnu, The number means nothing here. I just assigned some random excess amount. Per Year could be more or it could be less than other excess amounts. I just need to split based on the "Text" not the value.

Comment: The question wasn't about the numbers, @Cody , it was about the text, and how that effects what *column* the number just into.

Comment: @Larnu, I see what you mean. I have only these 5 combinations. Even if I get more combinations it simply should see the keywords like "Accident", "Condition". If any part of the input got Accident then it is considered as "ExcessPerAccident". If it got no keywords except "Year" only then it will go into "ExcessPerYear".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an option using a CROSS APPLY to alias the results of the CASE

```
Select Excess
      ,PerYear       = case when Class='PY' then value end
      ,PerAccident   = case when Class='PA' then value end
      ,PerCondidtion = case when Class='PC' then value end
 From  #SourceData A
 Cross Apply ( values ( case when charindex('Per Accident' ,Excess)>0 then 'PA'
                             when charindex('Per Condition',Excess)>0 then 'PC'
                             when charindex('Per Year'     ,Excess)>0 then 'PY' end
                        , try_convert(money,left(Excess,charindex(' ',Excess+' ')))
                      ) 
             ) B(Class,Value)
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Literally what I'd written, but just had an extra `TRY_CONVERT` to an `int`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h33HFJan)

Comment: @Larnu for some reason convert to money is a bit more forgiving.  I've yet to understand why.

Comment: I think it's just because monetary values often are written with a currency character, and separators for each 3 digits. I would guess that the conversion algorithm underneath strips those out prior.

Comment: @Larnu I get that, I just don't understand the inconsistency.  If I were writing a conversion, I would adopt more of a catholic approach (small c)